# Cannot download apps from Play Store on mobile data

Tags: google-play-store, mobile-data

I have LeEco Le 2 mobile. I am trying to download applications from Google Play Store - when I click on Install, it displays "Waiting for WIFI...".

I am on mobile data, but it is not downloading through mobile data.

How can I download apps through mobile data?

Answer (score 4):

First, go to your settings and under *Data usage* select *Cellular data usage*. Check whether the Google Play Store, Google Services and Download Manager are allowed to use background data.

If this doesn't help, go to *Apps* and find the Play Store. Tap on *Force Stop* and then tap on *Storage*. Tap *Clear Cache* (you could also clear all the data with the second button). Lastly, tap on *Permissions* and make sure that all of them are granted to the app.

Finally, reboot the phone. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this + ask every time before to download via mobile data + update firmware + activate & deactivate airplane mode several times until I got it working...not sure exactly what was the fixing move but airplone mode helped to connect to the google play store and eventually to allow downloads.

Comment: Toggling the airplane mode fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update the software first, go on 'setting' then 'software update' Download and install.

Comment: Mine worked when I changed the network preferences under the settings of google play app. The Auto-update apps should be allowed to be updated any time. Data charges may apply.

Answer (score -2):

You can press the "Download" icon, click Settings, and choose "No Limits".